# Multiple conditional statements in <head> of document

Tags: javascript, html, css, conditional-comments

I've got a script I want to run in every browser except versions of IE below 9, obviously, this conditional statements works for IE:

```
<!--[if gt IE 8]>
    JavaScript stuff here
<![endif]-->
```

But that code is then not executed in any other browser except IE9.

Is there any way of using multiple conditional statements together, e.g.

```
<!--[if gt IE 8 OR !IE]>
    JavaScript stuff here
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: You could just add a class to the body when is IE8 or less and only not run the script when the class is detected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use a conditional comment like this:

```
<!--[if gte IE 9]><!-->
    <script></script>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

There are two types of conditional comment: ones where the entire block is commented out of all browsers (your first version above) and ones where only the "condition" is commented out (this version here).

So all non-IE browsers see `<script></script>` outside of comments, IE before v9 parse the comments and know to ignore that HTML.

Answer (score 2):

It would be preferable for you to use **feature detection** rather than conditional comments. For example according to Microsoft documentation found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801214%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Internet Explorer 10 will completely ignore any conditional comments in your script such as:

```
  <!--[if IE]>
    This content is ignored in IE10.
  <![endif]-->
```

You can patch this by adding:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9">
```

But this is not a long-term solution.

Comment: Why is IE10 dropping support for conditional statements? Are conditional statements really that bad :S

Comment: Also could you please explain what you mean by feature detection? I think I might understand, but not 100% sure

Comment: The reason Microsoft gives on that link I provided for improved interoperability and compliance with HTML5.

Comment: Browser feature detection simply detects what features the browser supports. An example would be to use the modernizr library to detect whether a browser supports the HTML5 canvas element.

Answer (score 2):

You can use logical operators to "join" conditional statements like `[if (gt IE 5)&(lt IE 7)]` or `[if (IE 6)|(IE 7)]` as explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#syntax).

Using conditional statements to *comment content out* looks confusing, I wonder why so many answers suggested that. This is the notation I'm familiar with, with [more examples on quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html):

```
<!--[if IE]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE<br />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]> -->
According to the conditional comment this is not IE<br />
<!-- <![endif]-->
```

This syntax been recommended [in MS specs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), with more features like *custom version vector detection*. Keep in mind though that for all intents and purposes, IE10 will be detected as a non-IE browser and has to be referenced as one (hopefully with no more significant quirks to require addressing with conditional statements in the first place)

Answer (score 0):

I think that this page should help you out:

http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/conditional.html

Specifically:

```
I have found that the following code will allow you to target non-IE browsers

<!--[if !IE]><!-->
<h1>You are NOT using Internet Explorer</h1>
<!--<![endif]-->

..and finally to target non-IE and a specific IE browser
(or any combinations using lte lt or gt gte).

<!--[if IE 6]><!-->
<h1>You are using EITHER Internet Explorer version 6<br />
OR a non-IE browser</h1>
<!--<![endif]-->
<h1>You are using
<!--[if IE 6]>IE6 and not <!-->
a non-IE browser
<!--<![endif]--></h1>
```